# How do I code the release of a momentary touch sensor in IDE?

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, c++

I am a performing musician and quite new to the Arduino community.  Just learning as I go.  I am interested in using a momentary touch sensor with Adafruit's MP3 shield or Wave Shield.  I have successfully connected a touch sensor to the MusicMaker MP3 shield (which is sitting on the Adafruit Metro).  I combined some code from two independently working code sequences: one, to play MP3s and, two, to trigger with the sensor.  This works successfully except that the music starts but does not stop when I lift my finger off the sensor.  I want the music to stop when the touch sensor is not being touched.  When the sensor is touched again, I want the music file to start again from the beginning.  I'm printing the code IDE is running below and attaching an image of the touch sensor I am using.  I appreciate any advice on the code!  Thank you.

```
/*
  AnalogReadSerial

  Reads an analog input on pin 0, prints the result to the Serial Monitor.
  Graphical representation is available using Serial Plotter (Tools > Serial Plotter menu).
  Attach the center pin of a potentiometer to pin A0, and the outside pins to +5V and ground.

  This example code is in the public domain.

  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial
*/

// include SPI, MP3 and SD libraries
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_VS1053.h>
#include <SD.h>

// define the pins used
//#define CLK 13       // SPI Clock, shared with SD card
//#define MISO 12      // Input data, from VS1053/SD card
//#define MOSI 11      // Output data, to VS1053/SD card
// Connect CLK, MISO and MOSI to hardware SPI pins. 
// See http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI "Connections"

// These are the pins used for the breakout example
#define BREAKOUT_RESET  9      // VS1053 reset pin (output)
#define BREAKOUT_CS     10     // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define BREAKOUT_DCS    8      // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)
// These are the pins used for the music maker shield
#define SHIELD_RESET  -1      // VS1053 reset pin (unused!)
#define SHIELD_CS     7      // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define SHIELD_DCS    6      // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)

// These are common pins between breakout and shield
#define CARDCS 4     // Card chip select pin
// DREQ should be an Int pin, see http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt
#define DREQ 3       // VS1053 Data request, ideally an Interrupt pin

Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer musicPlayer = 
  // create breakout-example object!
  //Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(BREAKOUT_RESET, BREAKOUT_CS, BREAKOUT_DCS, DREQ, CARDCS);
  // create shield-example object!
  Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(SHIELD_RESET, SHIELD_CS, SHIELD_DCS, DREQ, CARDCS);

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Adafruit VS1053 Simple Test");

  if (! musicPlayer.begin()) { // initialise the music player
     Serial.println(F("Couldn't find VS1053, do you have the right pins defined?"));
     while (1);
  }
  Serial.println(F("VS1053 found"));

   if (!SD.begin(CARDCS)) {
    Serial.println(F("SD failed, or not present"));
    while (1);  // don't do anything more
  }


  // Set volume for left, right channels. lower numbers == louder volume!
  musicPlayer.setVolume(20,20);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  if(sensorValue > 100) {
    Serial.println(F("Playing track 001"));
  musicPlayer.playFullFile("/track001.mp3");
  }
 else(sensorValue < 100); {
    Serial.println(F("Paused"));
  musicPlayer.pausePlaying("/track001.mp3");
 }      }
```

Comment: you do it the same way as when you detect the keypress ... when the value of the pin indicates that the button has been released,  stop the music

Comment: I don't know the mp3 lib and its methods, but `playFullFile()` sounds like it may return **after** the entire file has been played. In that case the button wouldn't be polled while the file is being played

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon that doesn't belong in your code. Your current code (With the indentation cleaned up a little)

```
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  if(sensorValue > 100) {
    Serial.println(F("Playing track 001"));
    musicPlayer.playFullFile("/track001.mp3");
  }
  else(sensorValue < 100); { // <<<--semicolon does not belong here.
    Serial.println(F("Paused"));
    musicPlayer.pausePlaying("/track001.mp3");
  }
}
```

Should be:

```
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  if(sensorValue > 100) {
    Serial.println(F("Playing track 001"));
    musicPlayer.playFullFile("/track001.mp3");
  }
  else(sensorValue < 100) { // <<<--semicolon removed from this line
    Serial.println(F("Paused"));
    musicPlayer.pausePlaying("/track001.mp3");
  }
}
```

With the semicolon after the else, your code reads "...else do nothing" and then I would expect it to execute the pause logic no matter what value is in `sensorValue`.

You should pick an indentation style and then be absolutely consistent with it. Most C/C++ programmers use K&R style, which is what I used in my edit. (Opening braces are on the same line as the if statement/function that begins the scope, code inside braces is indented, and closing brace is at the same indentation level as the line that contains the opening brace.)

Answer (score 0):

As Sim Son have pointed it out, you need to use the proper function.
According to your library's [documentation](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-vs1053-mp3-aac-ogg-midi-wav-play-and-record-codec-tutorial/library-reference):

boolean playFullFile(char *trackname) - Play the complete file. This function will not return until the playback is complete.

You want to check your touch sensor, so this won't be enough for you.

boolean startPlayingFile(char *trackname) - Begin playing the specified file from the SD card using interrupt-driven playback. This allows your program to perform other tasks as the file is playing.

That documentation missed it, but in the source there is a function that stops your music:

void stopPlaying(void);

You can find this within your Arduino folder: Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_VS1053_Library's Adafruit_VS1053.h and Adafruit_VS1053.cpp files.